# Est-ce que les Français Européens ne comprends pas nos expressions ou est-ce qu'ils juste ne les préfèrent pas?

Tags: vocabulaire, usage, régionalismes

J'ai appris français de mes grand-parents. C'était notre langue privée dans une société anglophone. Mais je n'appris écrire français avant la lycée. Dont, je suis toujours un peu "wrong-footed" quand je charre avec des Français qui sont étrangers.
Par exemple :
Chez nous, on dit'
Qui c'est qu'a pris ma plume?
A quoi faire t'es sorti si tarde hier au soir? (synonyme de pourquoi).
Que c'est que ca?
Je n'aime pas patiner 'a cause que je tombe trop souvent. (synonyme de parce que).
As-tu il va venir avec? (Au lieu de Est-ce qu'il va venir avec nous?)
Nous-autres, on va au cinema demain 'a soir.
Clare pis moi on va 'a Macdonalds 'a cause qu'on est affamé!

Et bien d'autres expressions comme celles!

Je suis physicien et mathématicien; et je voyage en France de temps en temps. Je trouve que quand j'utilize mon petit français, et surtout les expressions courantes chez nous, on ne me comprends pas-- ou plus souvent on me corrige.

Est-ce ces usages sont considérés << outre's  >> ?

Comment: Pour ma part, elles sont, effectivement, difficilement compréhensibles (je suis Français).

Comment: Certaines expressions sont difficiles à comprendre (*as-tu*, *à quoi faire*), d'autres sont assez transparentes mais défavorisées (*à cause que*, *qui c'est qui*). Je les trouve belles en tout cas.

Comment: C'est où, chez nous ?  On pourrait réviser le titre de *nos expressions* à *ces/nos expressions de [région]* pour clarifier. C'est facultatif mais intéressant.  Bienvenue sur French language SE.

Comment: Certaines expressions peuvent être inconnues même hors de votre famille - c'est toujours une possibilité.

Comment: Il s'agit d'un problématique classique entre un langue "privée" parlée uniquement à la maison et une langue parlé aussi bien à la maison qu'ailleurs dans la société : on ne parle certes le même français à la maison et dehors, mais les normes du français "officiel" influencent aussi le français parlé chez soi.

Answer (score 3):

> *Qui c'est qu'a pris ma plume?*

C'est une tournure courante à l'oral. En revanche, on risque de ne pas comprendre de quelle plume il s'agit à cause de l'incohérence de registres entre la grammaire et le vocabulaire.

> *À  quoi faire t'es sorti si tarde hier au soir?* (synonyme de pourquoi).

*À  quoi faire* va poser problème et on se dira que tu as voulu dire "*Pour quoi faire, tu es sorti si tard hier soir ?*", ce qui doit correspondre au sens attendu.

> *Que c'est que ca?*

C'est courant en français relâché quands les *e* sont muets (Qu'c'est qu'ça) mais on entendra plus *Qu'est-c'est qu'ça ?* ou mieux *C'est quoi ça ?*

> *Je n'aime pas patiner à cause que je tombe trop souvent.*

*A cause que* est compris mais sera souvent repris, car considéré comme trop "incorrect". Il ne s'agit pourtant que d'un [archaïsme](https://www.academie-francaise.fr/cause-que). (Idiomatique en français: *J'aime pas faire du patin [à glace] parce que je tombe trop souvent.*)

> *As-tu il va venir avec?* (Au lieu de "Est-ce qu'il va venir avec nous?")

Le *As-tu il va venir* est incompréhensible en France et la phrase semble tronquée après *avec*. Elle sera probablement mieux comprise en Belgique et dans l'Est de la France où *[venir avec](https://francaisdenosregions.com/2018/04/16/les-regionalismes-du-grand-est/)* sans complément existe. (Idiomatique en France: *I(l) vient avec nous ?*)

> *Nous-autres, on va au cinema demain 'a soir.*

Pas habituel mais très compréhensible. (Idiomatique: *Nous, on va au ciné[ma] demain soir*).

> *Clare pis moi on va à Macdonalds à cause qu'on est affamé!*

Plutôt compris si on sait que *Clare* est un prénom, ce que je suppose. On risque aussi de comprendre que vous y allez l'un à la suite de l'autre (puis) plutôt qu'ensemble. (Idiomatique: *Clare et moi, on va au MacDo parce qu'on crève la dalle !*)

En France, on a peut-être plus tendance qu'ailleurs à reprendre et corriger les fautes de français, ou perçues comme telles, de ses enfants, amis et parfois collègues. C'est une marque de proximité. L'intention n'est généralement pas d'humilier ou de vexer ses interlocuteurs mais de leur permettre d'améliorer leur français, ou plutôt ici de le mettre en conformité avec une langue plus normative et locale. Trop le faire est certainement une mauvaise idée car ces interruptions ne peuvent que perturber les personnes qui s'expriment.